# Can you play an instant (airlift) to move quarantine specialist prevent infection after the infection card has been drawn?

Tags: pandemic

We had a situation where in the infection stage, a city was drawn that was about to cause an outbreak.

To stop this, we used an instant to move out quarantine specialist there.

Is this within the rules, or cheating?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is against the rules.

You must resolve each card fully before you can do anything else, so if you draw a card that causes an outbreak, you must first perform all of its steps. After you resolve that, you can play an Event, if you like. And, of course, you could play an instant before drawing and revealing the first Event card.

From the [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Pandemic.pdf), page 7:

> Event cards can be played at *any time*, *except* in between
>   drawing and resolving a card.

You might also be interested in this similar question: [In Pandemic, when does the discard-over-7-cards rule take effect?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/17997/in-pandemic-when-does-the-discard-over-7-cards-rule-take-effect).

Comment: So, not quite the same as an "instant" in M:TG, where you're allowed to see the card about to be played, then act before it actually "lands" and has any effect.